# Why is the flight time of London-Beijing and Tel Aviv-Beijing the same?

Tags: air-travel, london, beijing, geography, tel-aviv

Flight time between London and Beijing is around 10hrs nonstop.
Same goes for Tel Aviv and Beijing. 
Why is that? there's a 5hrs flight that separates London from Tel Aviv. Does it have to do with different travel paths of each plane?

Comment: The Israeli plane takes a big detour around the Middle East.

Comment: Any resources to read up on this?

Comment: TLV-PEK is only [500 miles shorter](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=LON-PEK,TLV-PEK) than LON-PEK. (If the carriers fly the shortest possible route, which often they do not.) Note that TLV lies nowhere near the shortest-distance route on LON-PEK, so the five hours has not bought you anything along your journey towards PEK (it's almost in the wrong direction). Depending on equipment constraints, routing constraints, and carrier preference for extra padding time, it is not surprising that the flights have similar block times.

Comment: [The polar aspect map](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=LON-PEK%2CTLV-PEK&MS=wls&MP=p&DU=mi) makes it clearer.

Comment: Somewhat similar issues with Europe - East Coast / West Coast Canada: London - Toronto is 7:50, London - Vancouver is 9:35 and Toronto - Vancouver is 5 hours.

Comment: "Flight time between London and Beijing is around 10hrs nonstop. Same goes for Tel Aviv and Beijing. Why is that? there's a 5hrs flight that separates London from Tel Aviv." Why shouldn't it be? Just because A and B are not at the same position doesn't mean the travel time to C from A or B isn't the same. To make this question useful you should have provided more arguments that indicate that travel times should not be equal.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In part this is due to flights from Tel Aviv avoiding some problem regions. But a larger part is that, while it is a 5 hour flight from London to Tel Aviv, flights from London to Beijing don't fly anywhere near Tel Aviv.

Looking at a typical [Mercator projection map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection), it may seem like a flight from London to Beijing wouldn't have to go very far out of its way to stop in Tel Aviv. But that map horribly distorts distances at different latitudes.

In fact the actual distance from London (Heathrow) to Beijing is 8162 km while Tel Aviv to Beijing is 7149 km. London-Tel Aviv is 3593 km.

If you look up some flights for actual routes. London-Beijing is close to flying direct (8400 km) while Tel Aviv-Beijing goes further out of its way (7800 km)

[image]
  - Flights BA 39 and HU 7958. Data from [FlightAware](http://flightaware.com)

Keep in mind that the more northerly route is more distorted, making it look longer on this map.

So in the end there is only about 600 km difference in the actual flight path. About 45 minutes. Both flights took about the same time (9 hours 30 minutes). The remaining difference is likely due to different prevailing winds, different airplanes etc.

Comment: "But that map horribly distorts distances at different latitudes.": [obligatory](https://xkcd.com/977/)

Comment: Wonder why they fly kinda towards Georgia, but then detour around it at the Black Sea, are they avoiding just parts of Turkey?

Comment: Sometimes it has to do with agreements. Certain airlines avoid certain airspaces (possibly to avoid paying fees?).

Comment: @MartinArgerami Fees not so much in this case. Syrian airspace is pretty much closed to any civilian traffic due to the conflict and no Israeli plane is getting anywhere near Iran or IS held territory. So detouring north is pretty logical.

Comment: @Calchas Even more obligatory: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVX-PrBRtTY

Comment: @Tonny - that explains bypassing Syria, but not Georgia...

Comment: @Tonny That's true but I think it's been like that for a longer time. Handover between Lebanese and (I think) Syrian ATC and Israeli ATC has been impossible for years if not decades. Royal Jordanian, which has no problem with crossing Israel when flying from Europe to Amman already had to circumvent it before the war and now go all the way to Egypt when flying out of Beirut. Middle East Airlines still flies over Syria as we speak (or at least they did a couple of weeks ago). Nick's question was about the little detour further up on the map, though.

Comment: @NickT: Just eyeballing the flight track, it looks as if the parts over Turkey, China and Mongolia line up into an approximate great circle route (that would cross Georgia if flown directly), while the middle part that goes over Russia and Kazakhstan is shifted north. Presumably, for some reason, when they decided to detour around Georgia they only changed the middle part of the route. Others can probably take a better guess at the exact reasons, though.

Comment: @NickT I'm thinking they're staying as far as possible from [Donetsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_17) while also avoiding [Abkhazia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abkhazia) and the [Russia-Georgia border](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia–Russia_relations) in general.

Answer (score 6):

The great circle distance from LHR to PEK is 8174km and the scheduled flight time is 10:10 (British Airways). The great circle distance from TLV to PEK is 7155km and the scheduled flight time is 9:20.

There is no condradiction between a 1000km difference in flight distance and a 50 minute difference in scheduled flight time.

Comment: I'm not so sure that I'd say there's "no contradiction", unless you're implying that the airliners routinely cover that extra distance at an average speed of (1000 km)/(50 minutes) = 1200 km/h ≈ Mach 1.1 at airliner cruising altitude.

Comment: I suppose it could be the case that airliners from LHR–PEK routinely have a faster groundspeed than those from TLV–PEK due to the effects of the jet stream at higher latitudes.  But claiming that it only takes an airliner an extra 50 minutes to cover an extra 1000 km requires a bit more justification and/or qualification.

Comment: I think what's missing here is a discussion of actual-route distances between the city pairs, as opposed to the distances along the great-circle routes. As @Kris notes in his answer, the difference between the actual-route distances is much smaller than is the difference between the great-circle distances.